# Issue with import tensorflow: SystemError: initialization of _pywrap_checkpoint_reader raised unreported exception

Tags: python, tensorflow

Working on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine, within Spyder 3.9, with tensorflow 2.15 installed.

Simply trying to import the package, I run and return the following errors:

```
import tensorflow as tf
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_275746/3793406994.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import distribute

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/distribute/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__.distribute import combinations

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/distribute/combinations/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.combinations import env # line: 456

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/combinations.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import collective_all_reduce_strategy

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/collective_all_reduce_strategy.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import cross_device_ops as cross_device_ops_lib

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import cross_device_utils

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import values as value_lib

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_lib

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 206, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.ops import dataset_ops

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.ops import iterator_ops

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.saver import BaseSaverBuilder

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training import py_checkpoint_reader

  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_checkpoint_reader import CheckpointReader

SystemError: initialization of _pywrap_checkpoint_reader raised unreported exception
```

I do see the first line `RuntimeError` re `numpy`, but numpy version was checked and requirement met as part of the tensorflow install.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the numpy version works for me. Try this:

`pip install numpy --upgrade`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).